# Lemmatization of slang words in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, lemmatization

I'm trying to train an SVM for Twitter text classification. Obviously, tweets tend to contain a lot of words that are slang or misspelled relative to formal documents that are more common to NLP. Here's an example of a tweet I'm trying to classify:

```
Word I'm bout to holla at her via twitter RT @iamJay_Fresh : #trushit - im tryna fucc nicki minaj lol
```

I want to know if it's possible to stem/lemmatize this text so the slang words are corrected and it looks something like this:

```
Word I'm about to holler at her via Twitter RT @iamJay_Fresh : #trushit - I'm trying to fuck Nicki Minaj lol
```

Note: I'm not too concerned about expanding common acronyms like "lol" to "laughing out loud". The reason I want to lemmatize is to reduce data sparsity: if the SVM has seen "holler" many times in a negative context but "holla" only a few times because people use it less, it would benefit from using the connotation of "holler" to classify a tweet with "holla". OTOH "lol" is commonly used in positive tweets so if the SVM sees another "lol" it'll know about its polarity even though it's not formal English.

Comment: I would say you should use something like [FlashText](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) to help you out, although that would require you to hardcode the slangs.